# Retrieving every Result from Google Search

Tags: google-maps, jsoup

I want to get literally every search result from a certain term. For example if I have the term "dentist las vegas" I want to get at least 5000 results with all links google provides.

I want to make it with jsoup. Do anyone have a sample code for me please?

Comment: Google's APIs are rate limited and subject to a quota (plus a cost), in general they make it hard to get **every** response (and attempting to do so is probably against the terms of use)

Comment: Your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458740/get-site-links-from-google-search) was much better, since it showed some effort you have done, but if nobody answered you there, what makes you think that posting it again will do any good?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Google Maps Platform's Text Search Request**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) if you wish to get the results of all "dentists in Las Vegas" including their websites and other information. The service is especially useful for making **ambiguous address queries** in an automated system, and non-address components of the string may match businesses as well as addresses.

Below is a sample request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=dentists+in+Las+Vegas&key=YOUR_API_KEY

There's an optional parameter "**pagetoken**" wherein it returns up to 20 results from a previously run search. Setting a pagetoken parameter will execute a search with the same parameters used previously — all parameters other than pagetoken will be ignored.